# Best way to create a global loading screen with bloc?

Tags: flutter, bloc, scaffold, flutter-widget

I tried to create a loading screen widget on top of the widget tree stacked with its first scaffold. It works fine inside that scaffold. When I navigator.push to another scaffold and try to trigger the loading screen, it doesn't appear on the second scaffold. It only works on top of the first scaffold.

I saw an approach with a single scaffold app. But it is not suitable in my context. Is there any way to create a stack that affects all scaffolds underneath it or **WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO USE A GLOBAL LOADING SCREEN, DIALOG BOX WITH BLOC**

[image]

Comment: "Always-on-top" modals are implemented with Navigators in Flutter. Things like [Dialogs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html) are just Navigators, and they do a great job of blocking the screen no matter what.

Comment: Another approach is to wrap your `MaterialApp` in a `Stack`. This is a bit hard to get right depending on what widget you render on top of the app, because `MaterialApp` gives `ThemeData` to widgets. You'll have to do some manual styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to create a global loading screen or dialog box is to use the [get package](https://pub.dev/packages/get) route management functions, all you need to do is to wrap your widget tree with

`GetMaterialApp` instead of `MaterialApp`

and then you can call

`Get.generalDialog(...)` or `Get.dialog(...)`

anywhere in the app. And if you decide to use another means like flutter's inbuilt `showDialog(...)` and need access to the base MaterialApp's context, you can call `Get.context`